Getting Active Directory "SecurityDescriptor" attribute in .net core on linux machine
I'm using the following c# .net core code to get the ntSecurityDescriptor attribute from Active Directory server.
I'm using the Novell.Directory.Ldap library because I need this code to run on a Linux machine.
using (var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection { SecureSocketLayer = false })
{
    ldapConnection.Connect(_ldapHost, _ldapPort);
    ldapConnection.Bind(_loginDN, _password);

    var constraints = new LdapSearchConstraints();
    constraints.SetControls(new LdapControl("1.2.840.113556.1.4.801", true
        , new byte[] {48, 3, 2, 1, 7}));
    
    ldapConnection.Constraints = constraints;
    
    var searchFilter = "(objectClass=user)";
    var searchResults = ldapConnection.Search(
        _searchBase,
        LdapConnection.ScopeSub,
        searchFilter,
        null,
        false
    );
    var accessRules = new List<ActiveDirectoryAccessRule>();
    while (searchResults.HasMore())
    {
        var nextEntry = searchResults.Next();
        var userAttributes = nextEntry.GetAttributeSet();
        var acl = userAttributes.GetAttribute("ntSecurityDescriptor");
        var byteValue = userAttributes.GetAttribute("nTSecurityDescriptor").ByteValue;
        var security = new CommonSecurityDescriptor(true, true, byteValue, 0);

        foreach (var acl in security.DiscretionaryAcl)
        {
           var accessRule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(
           ((KnownAce)acl).AccessMask,
           ((KnownAce)acl).SecurityIdentifier.Value,
           ((QualifiedAce)acl).AceQualifier,
           acl.IsInherited,
           acl is ObjectAce ? ((ObjectAce)acl).ObjectAceType : Guid.Empty,
           acl is ObjectAce ? ((ObjectAce)acl).InheritedObjectAceType : Guid.Empty,
           acl is ObjectAce ? ((ObjectAce)acl).ObjectAceFlags : ObjectAceFlags.None,
           acl.PropagationFlags
           );
        accessRules.Add( accessRule );
       }
    }
}

The problem is that the System.Security.AccessControl types (CommonSecurityDescriptor, KnownAce, QualifiedAce, ObjectAce etc.) are only supported on windows.
How can I get this info on a linux machine?

I used the mono project objects and code instead of the microsoft ones. e.g.:CommonSecurityDescriptor
